# Python: Start media playback in new parallel process

Tags: python, media-player

For a small media library which allows me to rate media while it is playing i need to run the media and a python shell simultaniously. This is what I had in mind:

```
def play(path):
  os.execlp("vlc.exe", "vlc.exe", path)

process = multiprocessing.Process(target=play, args=(somePath,))
process.start()
input("Press Enter to kill process")
process.terminate()
```

The shell works as inteded, but nothing is played. VLC is not started.

If I directly call play, vlc is started an the media starts playing. But then of course I loose control over the python shell.

Comment: Remember to accept answers :D

Answer (score 1):

Open it as a subprocess using the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html)

```
subprocess.call('vlc.exe my video')
```